# what are the different techniques of creating dom elements in javascript and their comparison. which one is better and why?

Tags: javascript, dom

There are many ways to create dom element. through string by passing it innerhtml and by using createelement function of javascript. Thats all i know.

I want to know which technique is better when using for big javascript apliations. maybe some comparison of performance would shed light.

this is what as web application developer used frequently without knowing the outcomes.

Comment: You can go to jsperf to test the speed diff yourself, and also see some stats: http://jsperf.com/dom-vs-innerhtml/10

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the application.  Setting a large number of elements with *innerHTML* should be faster, but using *createElement* gives you more control over the element before you add it to the DOM.  Often, people make the mistake of manipulating the *innerHTML* property inside a loop over many iterations, which is very bad for performance, so ensure that you set it after any loops have ended.

For small dom manipulations, I would stick to *createElement*.  It's easier to maintain and feels more structured than using *innerHTML*.  Also, remember that *innerHTML* might not be supported in some older, non-Internet Explorer browsers.

Comment: +1 for DOM methods, also good to note that using innerHTML adds to the risk of the programmer making mistakes in the HTML formatting.  DOM is just cleaner usually.  Only if speed difference is really noticeable would I consider innerHTML.

Comment: @XHR: that's also a good point - I remember there's a few quirks where Internet Explorer will throw errors if certain elements are put where they're not allowed.  That's not necessarily a bad thing, but the error messages themselves aren't very descriptive so there's a chance it could confuddle anyone for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Andy E that using innerHTML is easier but using innerhtml is a real performance killer. for example creating a simple table using innerhtml will take more time withsimple data. where as it would only take a fraction by using creatElement DOM element function.

createElement takes a lot of time to program but this can be overcome by using jQuery library. Doing work with jQuery will really short your code, make it cross browser and will have a huge performance comapred to innerHTML technique

I have done a whole comparison of these techniques, its hard to sum everything up here, please refer to this article and hopefully your mind will be in ease after going though this long article.

http://aspilham.blogspot.com/2011/01/creating-dom-elements-in.html